# high scores java with arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I am writing the following high scores game, using ArrayLists and void methods. Im having trouble with the required output, which should look similar to the following:

```
Top Scorers:
Name1: 600
Name2: 400
Name3: 300
Name4: 200
Name5: 100
```

The complex part I am having trouble with is the inputed name matching with the inputed score AFTER the score has been sorted in descending order. The following is the code I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;



public class high_scores {

//Write a program that records high-score data for a fictitious game. 
    //The program will ask the user to enter five names, and five scores. 
    //It will store the data in memory, and print it back out sorted by score.





    //array lists declared and initialized in main method; invoke other three methods
    public static void main(String args []) 
    {

        //creating an arraylist with names
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

        //creating an arraylist with scores
        ArrayList<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();


        //invoke other three methods
        initialize(names, scores);
        sort(names, scores);
        display(names, scores);

    }



    //user input of five names and five scores; 
    public static void initialize(ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<Integer> scores)
    {

        //for user input
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the name for score # 1: ");
        names.add(keyboard.next());
        System.out.print("Enter the score for score # 1: ");
        scores.add(keyboard.nextInt());

        System.out.print("Enter the name for score # 2: ");
        names.add(keyboard.next());
        System.out.print("Enter the score for score # 2: ");
        scores.add(keyboard.nextInt());

        System.out.print("Enter the name for score # 3: ");
        names.add(keyboard.next());
        System.out.print("Enter the score for score # 3: ");
        scores.add(keyboard.nextInt());

        System.out.print("Enter the name for score # 4: ");
        names.add(keyboard.next());
        System.out.print("Enter the score for score # 4: ");
        scores.add(keyboard.nextInt());

        System.out.print("Enter the name for score # 5: ");
        names.add(keyboard.next());
        System.out.print("Enter the score for score # 5: ");
        scores.add(keyboard.nextInt());


    }




    //function sorts both array lists based on values in scores array list
    public static void sort(ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<Integer> scores)
    {


            String array_names[] =  new String[names.size()];
            for(int x = 0; x < names.size(); x++) {
                array_names[x] = names.get(x);
            } 


            Integer array_scores[] = new Integer[scores.size()];
            for(int y = 0; y < scores.size(); y++) {
                array_scores[y] = scores.get(y);
            }


    }


    //method that displays the contents of the two arraylists
    public static void display(ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<Integer> scores)
    {   



        String array_names[] =  new String[names.size()];
        for(int x = 0; x < names.size(); x++) {
            array_names[x] = names.get(x);      
        } 


        Integer array_scores[] = new Integer[scores.size()];
        for(int y = 0; y < scores.size(); y++) {
            array_scores[y] = scores.get(y);

        }


            Arrays.sort(array_scores);


        System.out.println(array_names[4] + " : " + array_scores[4]);
        System.out.println(array_names[3] + " : " + array_scores[3]);
        System.out.println(array_names[2] + " : " + array_scores[2]);
        System.out.println(array_names[1] + " : " + array_scores[1]);
        System.out.println(array_names[0] + " : " + array_scores[0]);


    }
}
```

Based on our current levels, there are things I probably shouldn't include, like `compareTo, Collections, or Array.sort Descending.` Not sure...The given methods cannot be changed. So far, I have only managed to understand the first "`void initialize"` method and the `"void display"` method. The `"void sort"` method is confusing, which is why "sort" and "display" are similar. These are the step I have taken so far to get to this point:

```
1.) Initialize method: Array List user input
2.) Sort method: Converts Array List to Array; grabs Array List data
3.) Display method: Similar to sort; still working on display
```

My `"void display"` method is where I am having the most trouble. I have managed to print the inputed scores in descending order, but I just cant seem to match the index's of the `array_names` and the `array_scores` AFTER `array_scores` has been sorted. Any help will be super helpful.

Comment: hint : create a class, and don´t rely on two `List` beeing connected by theyr index.

Comment: If you are using two lists, then you have to sort them simultaneously based on one.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Score {
     private String name = null;
     private int score = 0;

     public Score(String name, int score) {
         this.name = name;
         this.score = score;
     }
}
```

you can then use this class for collection

```
List<Score> allScores = new ArrayList<Score>();
```

And add your input in following way:

```
allScores.add(new Score("Name1",600));
```

And you can sort this list by using custom comparator.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

if you cant use comparator, you need to have some workaround.
First you need a map with key the score and value list of the names

```
  Map<Integer,List<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer,List<String>>;
```

you fill this map before sortinglike this

```
      for(int i=0;i<scores;i++) {

            if(map.get(scores.get(i)) == null)
                 map.put(scores.get(i),new ArrayList<String>());
           map.get(scores.get(i)).add(names.get(i));
       }
```

After sorting the scores list all you need is to print the mapped list for each entry

```
     for(int i=0;i<scores;i++)
          printList(map.get(scores.get(i));
```